# Migrating to AngularJS: would controllers still have methods like initCreationForm?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I have been using Spring Pet Clinic to learn about various aspects of Spring, in particular Spring MVC. There is a variant of this project which uses AngularJS whereas the original project used Thymeleaf. In the original project, there were methods that look like this:

```
 @GetMapping("/owners/{ownerId}/pets/new")
public String initCreationForm(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Owner owner = this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId);
    Pet pet = new Pet();
    owner.addPet(pet);
    model.put("pet", pet);
    return "pets/createOrUpdatePetForm";
}
```

I see this in the AngularJS version -- in fact this is taken from the PetResource class of that project. I had imagined that all methods would just return json. So my question is, is this a mistake, something left over from the original project that should have been removed or is it correctly part of the AngularJS project?

Comment: Yes, it's probably a mistake.

Comment: Thanks, going to try to see if that code is ever entered,

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed unused code that has been removed now from the project.